# Rails Member Route Breaks Layout in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails controller named "claims" and an action named "addservice". 
as shown below

```
class ClaimsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_claim, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  layout 'dashboard'

  def addservice
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Then in my route.rb file i have the following routes

```
resources :claims do 
  member do 
    get 'addService'
  end 
end
```

But the problem is whenever I visit the `addservice` route at

> localhost:3000/claims/1/addservice

for example, the static asset links in my dashboard layout breaks. And from the terminal I see the asset links are now namespaced as shown below with a new 'claims' directory added before the actual locations causing the links to the static files to break.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/claims/asset/plugins/style/css/style.css"):
```

It works normally when I visit the new action in the claims controller and others but never for the namespaced route.

The links in my dashboard.html.erb layout file are shown below:

```
<link href="../asset/plugins/style/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../asset/plugins/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove these stylesheets from dashboard layout files

```
<link href="../asset/plugins/style/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../asset/plugins/css/bootstrap-extension.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And now you can create a new css files inside the app/assets/stylesheets directory

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/dashboard.css

/*
*= require dashboard/style
*= require dashboard/bootstrap-extension
*/
```

Now you can create a dashboard directory inside the app/assets/stylesheets directory and place those files inside the dashboard directory.

Now add dashboard css file to assets initializers for assets precompile

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( dashboard.css )
```

Add dashboard css file to dashboard layout -

```
# app/views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb  
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'dashboard', media: 'all'%>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: i am using a custom template and i need the asset files and ordering to remain intact. moving them to the application stylesheets folder will cause it to be compressed the the order of loading the stylesheets will be lost messing up the layout.

Comment: HI @skillzAlonge, I modified the total answer based on your above comment. Please follow the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'%>
```

and require this assets in your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
In this file you will file the folowing documentation :

> This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files listed below. Any CSS and
>   SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets,
>   vendor/assets/stylesheets, or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins,
>   if any, can be referenced here using a relative path. You're
>   free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
>   the bottom of the compiled file so the styles you add here take
>   precedence over styles defined in any styles defined in the other
>   CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a
>   new file per style scope.

Your problem is that using a relative path as you do here can't work.

Comment: i need a way to keep the assets statically declared in the layouts file

Comment: my major challenge is getting rid of the added "claims" directory for the namespaced route. is there any way i can achieve this ?

Comment: try to use :

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style/css/style' %>`
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'css/bootstrap-extension.css' %>`